# ¿Cómo subir un PDF a MongoDB con Vue, NodeJS?

Tags: nodejs, vue.js, mongodb, pdf, fileupload

Alguien sabe como subir un archivo pdf a mongodb? estoy usando el stack mevn , he estado leyendo documentación pero no he encontrado la manera.

Estoy tratando de convertir el pdf a base64 para mandarlo a la coleccion de mongodb.

Alguien tiene una idea mejor?

Answer (score 0):

Aunque la mejor opción es guardar los archivos en un directorio o usando un S3, en MongoDB existe un Tipo de dato Binary, tendrias que subir de manera temporal el PDF para obtener el Buffer y luego almacenarlo en Mongo. Para descargarlo se me ocurre que podrias usar la API File de HTML5. Aqui pongo un ejemplo

```
var Binary = require(‘mongodb’).Binary; 
var data = fs.readFileSync(tu_archivo_pdf); 
var insert_data = {}; 
insert_data.file_data= Binary(data); 
var collection = db.collection(‘files’); collection.insert(insert_data, function(err, result){ ...
```

Ten en cuenta que los docs de mongo tienen un limite de 16MB. Como usas Express podrias usar el node package multer para subir tu archivo a un directorio temporal o obtener el buffer que quieres almacenar en el campo Binary de tu collection de mongo.